# Samba share not working (win10/ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, samba

I installed Win10. I have also installed vbox. Vboxhas a NAT host-only adapter. I added port forwarding to my NAT so I can ssh via it. I can also ssh via the host-only adapter.

Guest-OS is Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS. I've installed samba via the ubuntu installer.

So, the Problem is, I can't set up Samba. I'm a noob when it Comes to samba but until now I always was able to set it up and get it working but now I just don't know what's the Problem.

I followed this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!
So my settings are

```
[foo]
path = /home/me/foo
available = yes
valid users = me
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

As they said I added it to the end of the file.

Now, sometimes I see my server listed in the network. (Sometimes I don't, I really don't get it) If I do, I can't connect. As usual at Windows, the error msg isn't helping, it says "can't Access". I also can't Access it via explorer directly.

I just have no clue why it doesn't work at all.

I really hope you can help me. I've googled for like 6 hours and I just can't anymore.

Ah btw: sudo smbstatus --Shares doesn't show anything - it used to. . . I didn't rly change a lot, I basically just tried a few different configs but nothing big.

I have a local win10 account.

Edit:

I used to be able to  smbclient //devserver/www -U me on my server. Doesn't work anymore.

Edit2:
I reinstalled Ubuntu server, now I use the above config, which is basically the same. I can now Access the samba share on the server itself but still the same problem from Windows.

Edit3: I just saw that Windows says "network path not found" and 0x80070035 but it's listed in network.

Comment: Is that setting list verbatim? If so there is a typo. First line should be `[www]`.

Comment: I just reinstalled the server and did the tutorial again. I updated the config in the init post but the missing ] was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the ending ] at the share name --> [www]

Also, I didn't find an "available" option in the docs, maybe just use writable and browsable.

Comment: I just reinstalled the server and did the tutorial again. I updated the config in the init post but the missing ] was a typo. Thanks for pointing out the issue with  available option. I'll check it.